# Customization soap response

Tags: java, soap, cxf

i am working on web services project with Apache CXF.
I wan't to handle exception and customize response:

```
public class FaultInterceptor extends
AbstractSoapInterceptor {

public FaultInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.MARSHAL);
}
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage soapMessage) throws Fault {
Fault fault = (Fault) soapMessage.getContent(Exception.class);
QName faultCode = new QName("11111");
fault.setFaultCode(faultCode);
```

So here is what i get in the response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
  <soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:11111</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Message</faultstring>
  </soap:Fault>
 </soap:Body>
```

How can i remove the text "soap:" and let only 11111?

Please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To customize the SOAP response, you can implement either one of these:

- [JAX-WS handler](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html);
- [CXF interceptor](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html) (extend AbstractSoapInterceptor);
- Servlet Filter.

--EDIT 2019-02-20--

According to Javadoc (and SOAP spec), the faultcode must be in the form "prefix:localname" where "prefix" is the prefix of a declared XML namespace in your XML, or you can have no prefix - that you want - if it is declared as the default namespace, e.g. with `xmlns="my-custom-faultcode-namespace-uri"` somewhere, e.g. in the soap:Envelope element. So one way - not sure it's the easiest but it is SOAP standard compliant - consists to:

1) Make up your own custom namespace for this faultcode

2) Try changing the QName with empty string as namespace prefix:

```
QName faultCode = new QName("my-custom-faultcode-namespace-uri", "11111", "");
```

If this is not enough (I would be surprised it is that simple), you may have force CXF to use your custom namespace as the default (without prefix). According to [this post](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/How-to-customize-namespaces-position-and-prefix-in-CXF-response-td3423069.html), to customize namespaces and prefixes on the soap enveloppe in CXF, you change the Map in the jaxws 'soap.env.ns.map' property.

Comment: Thanks @Cyril for your response.i edited my request to be clair.FYI i have already implemnted AbstractSoapInterceptor.

Comment: OK I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the exactly same thing since migrating an old system to behave exactly the same.

I came up with the following Solution.

```
class SoapFaultEndpointInterceptor extends EndpointInterceptorAdapter
{
    private static final Pattern SOAP_CODE_FAULT_SPLITTER = Pattern.compile(":");


    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception
    {
        SaajSoapMessage soapResponse = (SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse();
        modifySoapFaultCode(soapResponse);

        return super.handleFault(messageContext, endpoint);
    }

    private void modifySoapFaultCode(SaajSoapMessage soapResponse)
    {
        try {
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = soapResponse.getSaajMessage();
            SOAPBody body = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();
            SOAPFault soapFault = body.getFault();

            modifyFaultCodeIfPresent(soapFault);
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            throw new SoapModifiyingException("Modifying faultcode did not work properly.", e);
        }
    }

    private void modifyFaultCodeIfPresent(SOAPFault fault)
    {
        if (fault != null) {
            String newFaultCode = cleanFaultCode(fault.getFaultCode());
            fault.setFaultCode(newFaultCode);
        }
    }

    private String cleanFaultCode(String oldFaultCode)
    {
        String[] cleanFaultCode = SOAP_CODE_FAULT_SPLITTER.split(oldFaultCode);
        Assert.isTrue(cleanFaultCode.length == 2, "No proper faultcode provided!");

        return cleanFaultCode[1].trim();
    }
```

And by adding `SoapFaultEndpointInterceptor` to your Interceptor, it should work.

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class SoapServerConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors)
    {
        interceptors.add(new SoapFaultEndpointInterceptor());
    }
}
```